# Confusing about substitute types

Tags: haskell

I am trying with effort to understand how types substitution works.

Consider following example:

```
*Lib Lib> :t id (*)
id (*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Let's look at the type signature of `id` and `(*)`:

```
*Lib Lib> :t (*)
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

*Lib Lib> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

How would I substitute types of `id (*)` without Prelude:

```
id  :: a -> a

(*) :: a -> ( a -> a ) "I did parentheses because of currying.
```

the first `a` of the `id`, will be substitute through `a -> ( a -> a )`

```
 id  :: |a          | -> a
 (*) :: |a -> a -> a|
```

because `a` is also the result type of `id`(is identify with `-> a`) then the type of `id` becomes to `a -> a -> a`.

Now consider more complicated example, how would I do the substitution with:

```
*Lib Lib> :t (+) . (*)
```

Type signature of `.` function:

```
*Lib Lib> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Now let's substitute the first argument with `(+)`:

```
(.) :: (+)
(.) :: (b ->|c)      -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) :: (a ->|a -> a) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Let's substitute the second argument with `(*)`:

```
(.) :: (+)           -> (*)    
(.) :: (b ->|c)      -> (a ->|b)      -> a -> c
(.) :: (a ->|a -> a) -> (a ->|a -> a) -> a -> c
```

Then substitute step by step until we get the final type:

```
(.) :: (b ->|c)      -> (a ->|b)      -> a -> c
(.) :: (a ->|a -> a) -> (a ->|a -> a) -> a -> c 

"the b on the first argument becomes to (a -> a), because
"of the substitution of the final type of second argument 
(.) :: (b        ->|c     ) -> (a ->|b)      -> a -> c
(.) :: ((a -> a) ->|a -> a) -> (a ->|a -> a) -> a -> c 

"the c, the final type becomes (a -> a), because the result
"type of the first argument
(.) :: (b        ->|c     ) -> (a ->|b)      -> a -> c
(.) :: ((a -> a) ->|a -> a) -> (a ->|a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
```

Wait, the final type that I've got above is wrong

```
(+) . (*) :: a -> a -> a
```

The right type would be:

```
*Lib> :t (+) . (*)
(+) . (*) :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

My question is, why do I get `(a -> a)`, there is no type parameter `b` at the end of the composition?

To clarify, what I mean, let's compare the final type parameter with the signature of the function composition:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a ->          -> c
                               a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

As you can I see, there is a hole between `a` and `c`, because `(a -> a)` is the type of `b`.
Why is the type parameter `b` suddenly between `a` and `c`?

I hope the explanation is understandable.

Comment: Ignoring constraints, you have a function of type `n->(n->n)` and you want to use it as the first argument of `(.)` which has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. So you unify `(b -> c)` with `n->(n->n)`. Now `b` becomes `n` and `c` becomes `n->n`, hence the type of `(.)` is `(n -> (n->n)) -> (a -> n) -> (a -> (n->n))` and the type of the application is `(a -> n) -> (a -> (n->n))`. Always give different type variables different names and you will have no problem performing substitutions.

Comment: If you further apply this to a function of type `m->(m->m)`, you have `a~m` and `n~(m->m)` so the function type becomes `(m-> (m->m)) -> (m -> ((m->m)->(m->m)))` and the result type is `(m -> ((m->m)->(m->m)))` which is (again, ignoring constraints) the right answer.

Comment: Mind that `a` is a type *variable*. The `a` in `id :: a -> a`, is not the same one as the one in for instance `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Comment: I forgot about application, that after the first application, the type parameter differs. Awesome, thanks so much.

Comment: One more example `*Lib> :t (+) id`, I did not get, why the signature is `(+) id :: Num (a -> a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

Comment: In `id (*)` the type of `id` does *not* become `a -> a -> a`. The type of `id` becomes `(a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a)` and the type of `id (+)` is `a -> a -> a`. (if I omit the `Num a =>` constraints from these types). The `a` in `id`'s type can be different from the `a` in `(*)`'s type!

Comment: What when I have a function with signature `a -> b` and pass as the first argument the `(+)` function, then `a` becomes `m` or `m -> (m -> m)` and why?